# In Chrome, container element width exceeds inner element width, after matchHeight applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I've got a page that's rendering in a strange way in Chrome-based browsers (particularly, Vivaldi); in Firefox, there is no problem. The page contains a span, which contains a link, and the link contains an image, like so:

```
<span class="container">
    <a href="...">
        <img class="content" src="...">
    </a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.container [
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

The [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) plugin is applied to align the height of the container with the height of an adjacent element.

```
$('.container').matchHeight({
    target: $('#adjacent_element')
});
```

If the height of #adjacent_element is 100px, and the image is, say 200px by 200px, after matchHeight is applied, the following happens in Chrome:

- The image will be rendered as 100px by 100px (good)
- .container will have a height of 100px (good)
- .container will have a width of 200px (problematic) - the width should match the width of the inner image, which is 100px. This problem does not occur in Firefox

To make things even more odd, if after the page is rendered, in Chrome, I pass the mouse cursor over .container, its width is adjusted to the desired width (i.e. 100px in the above scenario).

I'd like the page to render such that after matchHeight is applied, the width of .container is adjusted to the width of the image that it contains. Any suggestions on how to do this, without resorting to kludgy solutions that involve adding more javascript code? It seems that a combination of the matchHeight plugin and CSS should be sufficient to do this (and indeed, in Firefox, they are).